# Jquery UI Accordion's submenu item list is being overriden by the header div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Here is my jsbin 
https://jsbin.com/dukoqajuce/edit?html,css,js,output

WHat I am trying to do is open my submenu list when I click on main menu. However, it does pop out but is being overridden by the main div. Could anyone spot the problem please?

Here is the html code

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script><div      id="sidebar">
<ul  class="mainmenu">
    <div class="sidebarElementDiv">
        <div class="systemStatusNormal"> </div>
        <li class="sub-handle"><a class="sub-link" href="#!">STATUS</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">General</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!" id="statusNetwork">Network</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Timing</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">GNSS</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">PTP</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Alarms</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>   <!--End of STATUS li-->
    </div>  <!--End of sidebarElementDiv-->

    <div class="sidebarElementDiv">
        <div class="systemStatusNormal"> </div>
        <li class="sub-handle"><a class="sub-link" href="#!">NETWORK</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Ethernet</a> </li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">SNMP</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Ping</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebarElementDiv">
        <div class="systemStatusWarning"> </div>
        <li class="sub-handle"><a class="sub-link" href="#!">NTP</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">NTP Daemon Status</a> </li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">NTP Associations</a> </li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">NTP Config </a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">NTP MD5 Security Key </a></li>
                <li class="sub-li"><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">NTP Autokey</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the z-index on the .sidebarElementDiv. It is causing the submenu to appear below when the ul shows.

Comment: Tried what u suggested. Still same result.

Comment: I removed the line for z-index in the rule, and it corrected the issue for me in your jsbin. .sidebarElementDiv{
    width: 222px;
    background-color: #f1eff7;
    padding-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-left: 160px;
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
}

Comment: Ohh yes now It did. Thanks

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.